# Why can't use JSConext.setObject to UIWebView when js called location.reload() ?

Tags: javascript, swift, uiwebview, javascriptcore

I had write a ios app with Swift
When I want to use js call Swift's Object and Functions in UIWebView,
it appear some bugs.
As below is my codes:

```
    //a demo class that I want to export to UIWebView;
    //this object also was 
    @objc protocol  NavObj : JSExport{
            //any code here
            static func callMe() -> String;
    }
    @objc class NavObj : NSObject, NavObj{
            class func callMe() -> String{
                    return "called me";
            }
    }
    class someView : UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate{

            pubic func webView(
                    webView : UIWebView,
                    shouldStartLoadWithRquest request : NSURLRequest,
                    navigationType : UIWebViewNavigationType
            ) -> Bool {

                //get the JSContext
                var jsContext = webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext ;
                //and then set NavObj to UIWebView
                jsContext.setObject( NavObj.self , "NavObj" );
            }

    }
```

In UIWebView code like this:

```
       <script type='text/javascript'>
              //get a test
              var ret = NavObj.callMe();
              console.log(ret);
              //When first time to run this code was successed
              //But when use js's location.reload to refresh this page , it appear an error: 
              //NavObj was not defined. 

              location.reload();
       </script>
```

When first time to load the webpage it successed.
But when use js's location.reload to refresh this page , it appear an error: 
NavObj was not defined.

It means that my swift code

```
    jsContext.setObject( NavObj.self , "NavObj" );
```

was not worked.

Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: I'm very sorry to that I didn't copy full code to this post , the class `someView's UIWebView's delegate is self`.I write the codes in stackoverflow's html editor ...At the first paragraph of this post has some syntax error .

Comment: .At the first paragraph of this post has some syntax error .  `@objc protocol  NavObj : JSExport{` should changes to `@objc protocol  NavObjExport : JSExport{` AND  `@objc class NavObj : NSObject, NavObj{` should changes to `@objc class NavObj : NSObject, NavObjExport{`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a timing issue. When you navigate to a page or reload the page the JSContext will be deallocated and a new one created. The JSContext for a page is created while the page is loading but there isn't a way to know exactly when that happens.

I have found the most reliable approach is to use the `webViewDidFinishLoad` method to inject things into the JSContext and then trigger a DOM event when you are finished. In the web page you need to wait for that event before using the native objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.

Object must be set when webView finish load.

this line `jsContext.setObject( NavObj.self , "NavObj" );` move into `webViewdidFinishLoad:{}`

hope can help you